# Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I want to apply some sort of concatenation of the strings in a column using groupby.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
"name1","hej","2014-11-01"
"name1","du","2014-11-02"
"name1","aj","2014-12-01"
"name1","oj","2014-12-02"
"name2","fin","2014-11-01"
"name2","katt","2014-11-02"
"name2","mycket","2014-12-01"
"name2","lite","2014-12-01"
""")

# load string as stream into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(data,header=0, names=["name","text","date"],parse_dates=[2])

# add column with month
df["month"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

I want the end result to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 349, accepted):

You can groupby the `'name'` and `'month'` columns, then call `transform` which will return data aligned to the original df and apply a lambda where we `join` the text entries:

```
In [119]:

df['text'] = df[['name','text','month']].groupby(['name','month'])['text'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df[['name','text','month']].drop_duplicates()
Out[119]:
    name         text  month
0  name1       hej,du     11
2  name1        aj,oj     12
4  name2     fin,katt     11
6  name2  mycket,lite     12
```

I sub the original df by passing a list of the columns of interest `df[['name','text','month']]` here and then call `drop_duplicates`

**EDIT** actually I can just call `apply` and then `reset_index`:

```
In [124]:

df.groupby(['name','month'])['text'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

Out[124]:
    name  month         text
0  name1     11       hej,du
1  name1     12        aj,oj
2  name2     11     fin,katt
3  name2     12  mycket,lite
```

**update**

the `lambda` is unnecessary here:

```
In[38]:
df.groupby(['name','month'])['text'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

Out[38]: 
    name  month         text
0  name1     11           du
1  name1     12        aj,oj
2  name2     11     fin,katt
3  name2     12  mycket,lite
```

Comment: In `pandas < 1.0`, `.drop_duplicates()` ignores the index, which may give unexpected results. You can avoid this by using `.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))` instead of `.transform().drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: Neat and uncomplicated. Eminently fleixible also

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` might not work if you do not include parameter `drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` or just rewrite the line of code as 
`df = df[['name','text','month']].drop_duplicates()`

Comment: What ensures that the text e.g. in the first column is actually "hej du" and not "du hej"? Is there an implicit sort somewhere? How can I make this explicit, e.g. sort by the date column?

Comment: Why did 'hej,du' change to just 'du' in the "update" section?

Answer (score 142):

We can **groupby** the 'name' and 'month' columns, **then call `agg()` functions of Panda’s DataFrame objects.**

The aggregation functionality provided by the `agg()` function allows multiple statistics to be calculated per group in one calculation.

```py
df.groupby(['name', 'month'], as_index = False).agg({'text': ' '.join})
```

[image]

Comment: hi, any ideas for dropping duplicates with agg function ?

Comment: @kağanhazalkoçdemir
`agg({'text': lambda x: ' '.join(set(x))})`

Comment: How can one use this method in a case where NULLs are allowed in the column 'text' ?

Comment: `f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sequence item 45: expected str instance, NoneType found` on NULL or None values in the database

Comment: This also allows you to keep additional columns, for example by adding `, 'othercol': 'last'` into the `agg` dict

Comment: As an example, if you want to count the occurrences, add `, 'othercol: 'count'` to the list.

Answer (score 64):

The answer by EdChum provides you with a lot of flexibility but if you just want to concateate strings into a column of list objects you can also:

```py
output_series = df.groupby(['name','month'])['text'].apply(list)
```

Comment: Man, you've just saved me a lot of time. Thank you.
This is the best way to assemble the chronological lists of registrations/user ids into 'cohorts' that I know of. Thank you once again.

Comment: This solution worked for me very well for getting the unique appearances too. I just used “set” instead of “list” and then daisy chained a join and presto. Note that it doesn’t work if there are nan values, so I had to use fillna() on the text field first.  In my case the command ended: df.groupby(['doc_id'])['author'].apply(set).apply(", ".join).reset_index()

Comment: I don't think this adds spaces between the strings does it?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to concatenate your "text" in a list:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'month'], as_index = False).agg({'text': list})
```

Answer (score 13):

For me the above solutions were close but added some unwanted `/n's` and `dtype:object`, so here's a modified version:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'month'])['text'].apply(lambda text: ''.join(text.to_string(index=False))).str.replace('(\\n)', '').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try this line of code : -

```
df.groupby(['name','month'])['text'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Although, this is an old question. But just in case. I used the below code and it seems to work like a charm.

```
text = ''.join(df[df['date'].dt.month==8]['text'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the other answers, the following is probably the most concise and feels more natural. Using `df.groupby("X")["A"].agg()` aggregates over one or many selected columns.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                       'B' : ['i', 'j', 'k', 'i', 'j'],
                       'X' : [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]})

  A  B  X
  a  i  1
  a  j  2
  b  k  2
  c  i  1
  c  j  3

df.groupby("X", as_index=False)["A"].agg(' '.join)

  X    A
  1  a c
  2  a b
  3    c

df.groupby("X", as_index=False)[["A", "B"]].agg(' '.join)

  X    A    B
  1  a c  i i
  2  a b  j k
  3    c    j
```