# What's the equivalent for LISTAGG in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have the following aggregations:

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'first_seen': x['first_seen'].min(),
        'last_seen': x['last_seen'].max(),
        'md5s': x['md5s'].tolist(),
    }
    return pd.Series(names, index=['first_seen', 'last_seen', 'md5s'])
```

But in my results I have something like this, but I want a union of all md5s

```
  "md5s": [["md5_1", "md5_2"], ["md5_3"], ["md5_4", "md5_5"]]
```

What function should I use instead of tolist()?

These are my DataFrame and GroupBy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(some_data, orient='index')
gr = df.groupby(level=0, axis=0).apply(my_agg)
```

And some_data has the following format:

```
{"foo": {"first_seen": "2019-02-15", "last_seen":"2019-02-20",
         "md5s": ["md5_1", "md5_2", ...]},
 "bar": {...}}
```

Comment: I also had same question. check this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tolist() I had to put sum()

```
'md5s': x['md5s'].sum()
```

It was a little bit confusing because when you think about a sum, you think about adding numbers not joining lists. But it works!