# Using Pandas groupby to combine data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple Pandas dataframe that I wish to groupby using a certain column. The df looks like the one below.

```
Color    Car
  R      Ford
  O      Kia
  Y      Mazda
  R      Chevrolet
```

I want to groupby 'Color', so the resulting df would be:

```
Color    Car
  R      Ford, Chevrolet 
  O      Kia
  Y      Mazda
```

This seems to be easy enough using pandas groupby. My code looks like the following:

```
df = df.groupby(['Color'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Why does groupby not work? It seems like the most basic operation for which groupby is the perfect thing to use?

Comment: Aside from your error, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('Color')['Car'].apply(', '.join)
```

[out]

```
Color
O               Kia
R    Ford, Chevrolet
Y             Mazda
```