# Transformation - Putting information that exists in two columns in one row

Tags: python, pandas

I started learning python recently and I need your help. I have a dataframe with the following structure

[image: Dataframe]

I need to make a transformation, all values ​​in column 2 (product id) that have the same order_id (column 1) must become a row and the values ​​must be separated by commas.

Like this: 
[image: After transformation]

How can I make this transformation? Can somebody help me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired result using the following code

`df.groupby(['order_id'])['product_id'].apply(','.join).reset_index()`

You can refer to the following answer for more applications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298308/6908282

Comment: I used the code that you put on your answer and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) which is basically what you are asking for.