# How do i combine specific panda dataframe items into one item

Tags: python, pandas

I've written code to extract acronyms and other key words out of a PDF to create a glossary list. I've removed duplicates and sorted alphabetically and created a panda dataframe.

A portion of this dataframe (called gloss_of_terms1) looks like this:

```
    Acronyms/Abbrev
    0       EMP
    1       EFT
    2       FCF
    3       FY14
    4       FY15
    5       FY16
    6       GDN
    7       GP
```

I effectively want to write some code to group the items FY14, FY15, FY16 (separated by spaces) into one line and have the resultant dataframe look as follows:

```
    Acronyms/Abbrev
    0       EMP
    1       EFT
    2       FCF
    3       FY14 FY15 FY16
    4       GDN
    5       GP
```

I'm having no luck finding the correct tool/code to do this. Please help!

Comment: Without an MCVE I will not make a code based answer, but your best approach is to do a check on the first two letters as your reading it and place it in a list. Then use pandas to make the nested list into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has acheived something similar (concatenate in a group by) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

But you will also need to create a dummy index that you can apply the group by to, in this case, a substring of the first two characters. You could modify this substring if you wanted something different on the group by

```py
#Pandas library
import pandas as pd
#Create the dataset
df=pd.DataFrame({'Abbrev':['EMP','EFT','FCF','FY14','FY15','FY16','GDN','GP']})
#Dummy index with the substring (slice) to compare
df['ix']=df['Abbrev'].str.slice(0,2)
#Groupby concatenating the result
df=df.groupby(['ix'])['Abbrev'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
#Drop the dummy index
df=df.drop(['ix'], axis=1)
#Show result
df
```

For example, if you would rather have an IF condition on the first two letters matching FY you would replace the 6th line (where the IX is created) with:

```py
#Dummy index with the slice to compare
df['ix']=df['Abbrev'].apply(lambda x: x[0:2] if x[0:2]=='FY' else x)
```

Hope it helps, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you Ernesto! The only problem is that if there are other acronyms that start with the same 2 letters (i.e. CCO and CCM), it'll group these too. Is there anyway to make the slice specific to "FY". Or should i rather create a seperate filtered dataframe for all the FY items, perform your code, then replace the individual FY items with the grouped by FY's (does this make sense? or am i over complicating it?)

Comment: You can replace the function youa re using to create the index. I put an example of that in the answer!

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks Ernesto - much appreciated!