# Combine multiple rows in pandas dataframe and group them by columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

This is how my pandas data frame looks like.My requirement is to combine utterances column based on User_type and sorted by Chat_sequence_number and group them by case_id and Interaction_id

```
       Case_ID    Interaction_ID  Chat_Sequence_Number User_Type        Utterances
          1          123                   3           Person1            are
          1          123                   4           Person1              you
          1          123                   1           Person1              Hello,
          1          123                   2           Person1              how
          1          123                   5           Person1              feeling?
          1          123                   6           Person2              I'm
          1          123                   6           Person2              fine.
```

Is there a way that i can create a new data frame based on the requirements above.
My final Output should look like this

Case_ID    Interaction_ID  User_Type  utterance
1           123            Person1   Hello,how are you feeling?
1           123            Person1   I'm fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Please try to improve the format of the input and output, and explain what you've tried or found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a few steps:

1. Sort by Chat_Sequence_Number
2. groupby Case_ID, Interaction_ID, and User_Type
3. Use .apply() to concatenate the strings

This work is done in one line below

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Case_ID','Interaction_ID','Chat_Sequence_Number','User_Type','Utterances'])
df['Utterances'] = 'are','you','Hello','how','feeling?',"I'm",'fine.'
df['User_Type'] = ['Person1']*5+['Person2']*2
df['Chat_Sequence_Number'] = 3,4,1,2,5,6,7
df['Case_ID'] = 1
df['Interaction_ID'] = 123

# Do the grouping
output = df.sort_values(['Chat_Sequence_Number']).groupby(['Case_ID','Interaction_ID','User_Type'])['Utterances'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
print(output)
```

Output:

```
   Case_ID  Interaction_ID User_Type                  Utterances
0        1             123   Person1  Hello how are you feeling?
1        1             123   Person2                    I'm fine.
```