# Is there a way to groupby concatenating multiple strings?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
Name  Role     Company     [other columns]
John  Admin    GM
John  Director Kodak
John  Partner  McDonalds
Mark  Director Gerdau
Mark  Partner  Kibon
```

I want to turn it into:

```
Name    Companies                                              [other columns]
John    GM (Admin), Kodak (Director), McDonalds (Partner)
Mark    Gerdau (Director), Kibon (Partner
```

I think the answer is somewhere in the groupby field, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby) is almost there, however I need to find a way to do that iterating two columns and putting the parenthesis in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `assign` and `groupby`

```
df1 = df.assign(companies=df['Company'] + ' (' + df['Role'] + ')')\
                                            .groupby('Name')['companies'].agg(','.join)

print(df1)

Name
John    GM (Admin),Kodak (Director),McDonalds (Partner)
Mark                  Gerdau (Director),Kibon (Partner)
Name: companies, dtype: object
```

Comment: It is not aggregating here. Are you sure you didn't miss something? I'm using python 3.6.4

Comment: @abutremutante what output are you getting?

Comment: Just the company names, without aggregation