# Concatenate column values by id from another column with separator?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
dict_df = {'sent_id': {11: 3,
  12: 3,
  24: 7,
  25: 7,
  26: 7,
  27: 7,
  28: 7,
  29: 8,
  124: 15,
  125: 15,
  126: 15,
  133: 15,
  134: 15,
  135: 15,
  357: 26,
  358: 26,
  359: 26},
 'entity': {11: 'Zhao',
  12: 'Li',
  24: 'Beijing',
  25: 'PKU',
  26: 'Chinafront',
  27: 'Technology',
  28: 'Co.,',
  29: 'Ltd.',
  124: 'January',
  125: '1,',
  126: '2006',
  133: 'December',
  134: '31,',
  135: '2006.',
  357: 'RMB',
  358: '37,560',
  359: 'Yuan'},
 'label': {11: 'B-lessor',
  12: 'I-lessor',
  24: 'B-lessee',
  25: 'I-lessee',
  26: 'I-lessee',
  27: 'I-lessee',
  28: 'I-lessee',
  29: 'I-lessee',
  124: 'B-start_date',
  125: 'I-start_date',
  126: 'I-start_date',
  133: 'B-end_date',
  134: 'I-end_date',
  135: 'I-end_date',
  357: 'B-lease_payment',
  358: 'I-lease_payment',
  359: 'I-lease_payment'}}
```

And I want to concatenate it back to full sentence by `sent_id` with " " separator.

I have tried with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

`df.groupby("sent_id").agg(" ".join)` but I need to aggregate it to be:

```
January 1, 2006
```

What should I change to add separator or maybe there is a simpler method to do the same with unique values only in the label column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do, relying on [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby):

```
' '.join(df.groupby('sent_id')['entity'].transform(lambda row: ' '.join(row)).drop_duplicates())
```

which will give you:

```
Zhao Li Beijing PKU Chinafront Technology Co., Ltd. January 1, 2006 December 31, 2006. RMB 37,560 Yuan
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, could you point out what I misunderstand about your question, if I do miss something?

Comment: Thanks for your answer dear @zobop! 
Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I want.
I need to my final dataframe to look like:

```sent_id    entity                   label
1              January 1, 2006 here are the unique labels```

Comment: I mean I need to aggregate by id and concatenate the entities into one sentence and collect the labels into unique set.

I have solved it with 2 steps:
```from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
test_df[test_df.label != "O"].loc[:,["sent_id", "entity"]].groupby(["sent_id"]).agg(TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize)

test_df[test_df.label != "O"].loc[:,["sent_id", "entity"]].groupby(["sent_id"]).agg(TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize)```

Then join by id.