# Use groupby in Pandas dataframe but it's creating multiple rows with same value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe having 3 columns, let title, area, code. There are different values, including blanks in area and code columns for same title. I want to combine all these values of area and code separated by space such that there is one row for one title. I tried doing this using the code

```
df['area']=df['area'].replace("\\N",np.nan)
df['code']=df['code'].replace("\\N",np.nan)
df['area'] =df['area'].fillna('')
df['code'] =df['code'].fillna('')
df[['area','code']] = df.groupby(['title'])[['area','code']].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

I got what I wanted but this code is creating multiple rows having same data. For example if my dataset looks like this:

```
title   area    code
a       yv       f
a       ty       \N
a       dz       r
b       yv       \N
b       \N       f
c       dz       f
```

Then I want my output to be:

```
title   area          code
a       yv ty dz       f r
b       yv dz          f
c       dz             f
```

But I'm getting 3 duplicated rows for a, 2 for b and 1 for c containing same values. I can remove duplicate values later on, but my dataframe is very large (containing approx 2.4 million rows) and I'm not able to execute this command:

```
df[['area','code']] = df.groupby(['title'])[['area','code']].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

for it. So it would be helpful if I could remove duplicate values side by side, so that it doesn't take much RAM for processing. Or any other solution would be helpful too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest way (IMO) is:

```
df = df.groupby(['title']).agg(" ".join).reset_index()
```

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby) similar question too.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This is the fastest way to do this.