# Merge AND sum or concatenate (with TWO dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas

*([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby) does not explain what was requested below. There is the issue of merge before concatenation or sum, using these functions together to fill a column is the question.)*

I have two dataframes that look like these (obviously these are examples):

```
data1 = {'Name': ['Alex','Alex','Cristiano','Cristiano','Fernando','Jonas','William'], 'Color': ['Blue','Red','Black','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Green'], 
    'Codes': ['','','','','','',''], 'Values': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
data2 = {'Name': ['Jonas','Alex','Cristiano','Cristiano','Alex'], 'Color': ['Pink','Red','Black','Blue','Red'], 
    'Codes': ['1456','1450','1453','1530','1459'], 'Values': [12000.00,5000.50,78000.00,2000.00,1500.00]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Are so:

```
df1:
        Name   Color Codes  Values
0       Alex    Blue           NaN
1       Alex     Red           NaN
2  Cristiano   Black           NaN
3  Cristiano    Blue           NaN
4   Fernando  Yellow           NaN
5      Jonas    Pink           NaN
6    William   Green           NaN
df2:
        Name  Color Codes   Values
0      Jonas   Pink  1456  12000.0
1       Alex    Red  1450   5000.5
2  Cristiano  Black  1453  78000.0
3  Cristiano   Blue  1530   2000.0
4       Alex    Red  1459   1500.0
```

I want to fill the 'Codes' and 'Values' columns of df1 with the corresponding values ​​in df2 ('Code' and 'Values'), doing the matching of the columns 'Name' and 'Color'.

The problem is that there is more than one correspondence, for the column 'Codes' I want the concatenation of strings in 'Code' (separating with a comma), for the column 'Values' I want the sum of the correspondences.

I tried using merge, but this second part I don't know how to implement.
To be clearer, the desired output of df1 is this:

```
        Name   Color        Codes   Values
0       Alex    Blue                   NaN
1       Alex     Red  1450 , 1459   6500.5
2  Cristiano   Black         1453  78000.0
3  Cristiano    Blue         1530   2000.0
4   Fernando  Yellow                   NaN
5      Jonas    Pink         1456  12000.0
6    William   Green                   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) using `df1` as it is and a grouped version of `df2` (grouped by Name and Color). The [aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) should be `list` on Codes and `sum` on Values:

```
pd.merge(df1,
         df2.groupby(['Name','Color']).agg({'Codes':list,'Values':'sum'}).reset_index(),
         how='left',
         on=['Name','Color'],
         suffixes=('_x', ''))\
    .drop(['Codes_x','Values_x'],axis=1)
```

Which prints back:

```
        Name   Color         Codes   Values
0       Alex    Blue           NaN      NaN
1       Alex     Red  [1450, 1459]   6500.5
2  Cristiano   Black        [1453]  78000.0
3  Cristiano    Blue        [1530]   2000.0
4   Fernando  Yellow           NaN      NaN
5      Jonas    Pink        [1456]  12000.0
6    William   Green           NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you

Comment: Cool, glad it worked

Comment: @Wilian, could you please accept the answer if it's correct?

Comment: yes, most time https://stackoverflow.com/users/17014529/athing?tab=topactivity DV answers in pandas tag.

Comment: i kind of had a feeling it was this user actually.