# Pandas concatenate column values with comma after groupby()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | k | x |
| a | l | y |
| b | k | z |

I want to transform this dataframe to this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | "k,l" | "x,y" |
| b | k | z |

I found similar examples but couldn't find an exact solution to my problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `groupby` then `agg`

```py
df_ = (df.groupby(['Column1'])
       .agg({'Column2': lambda x: ','.join(x), 'Column3': lambda x: ','.join(x)})
       .reset_index()
)
```

```
print(df_)

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a     k,l     x,y
1       b       k       z
```

If you need the quote mark

```py
df_ = (df.groupby(['Column1'])
       .agg({'Column2': lambda x: f'"{",".join(x)}"' if len(x)>1 else x,
             'Column3': lambda x: f'"{",".join(x)}"' if len(x)>1 else x})
       .reset_index()
)
```

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a   "k,l"   "x,y"
1       b       k       z
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby(["Column1"], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ",".join(x))
```

**EDIT**
Just found out `lambda` is not even needed here:

```
df.groupby(["Column1"], as_index=False).agg(",".join)
```

Output:

```
    Column1     Column2     Column3
0   a           k,l         x,y
1   b           k           z
```

Comment: I believe that lambda is needed, without lambda it concatenates column names. Thank you

Comment: I tested it and it worked well for me ( don't have a deeper explanation why :P )

Comment: @1dll see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298308/15521392). seeing his reputation I think we can trust his statement. That's where I saw the idea and tried it out myself in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a custom function that joins the strings exploiting [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df.groupby(['Column1']).transform(lambda val: ','.join(val))
```

Comment: This solution duplicated rows, but other than that it works fine. Thank you!