# Get unique elements for each grouping and write to column in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so:

**Input:**

```
year ip   type
2020 101  Missing
2021 101  Type 1
2022 101  Type 2
2020 102  Missing
2021 102  Missing
2020 103  Missing
2021 103  Type 2
2021 104  Type 1
2022 104  Type 2
2022 104  Type 2
```

How can I convert my data frame to the following:

**Expected Output:**

```
ip  type
101 Missing/Type 1/Type 2
102 Missing
103 Missing/Type 2
104 Type 1/Type 2
```

Where I get all unique types for each IP. How can I do this in python pandas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case do `drop_duplicates` before `groupby.agg`

```
out = df.drop_duplicates(['ip','type']).groupby('ip')['type'].agg('/'.join).reset_index()
Out[638]: 
    ip                 type
0  101  Missing/Type1/Type2
1  102              Missing
2  103        Missing/Type2
3  104          Type1/Type2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `drop_duplicates` then `agg`

```py
out = df.drop_duplicates(['ip', 'type']).groupby('ip', as_index=False).agg('/'.join)
```

```
print(out)


    ip                   type
0  101  Missing/Type 1/Type 2
1  102                Missing
2  103         Missing/Type 2
3  104          Type 1/Type 2
```