# I want merge words with the same value in dataframe into one, stick the words next to each other at once

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I want merge words with the same value in dataframe into one, stick the words next to each other at once

ex)

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| acrania | a |
| acrania | b |
| acrania | c |
| acrania | d |

=>

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| acrania | a,b,c,d |

I want to make it in the form above.please help me

I was only able to remove duplicates in Excel, and it is too difficult for me to paste them sideways after removing duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your dataframe looks like this

```py
df = {'en': ['acrania', 'acrania', 'acrania', 'acrania'], 'ko': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

Simply use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```py
df = df.groupby('en')['ko'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        en       ko
0  acrania  a,b,c,d
```

Hope this helps.