# Use groupby on dataframe and concenate all rows into one

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this dataframe :

| ID | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new york |  | california |
| 2 | vermont; new york | carolina n | florida |
| 2 | oregon | texas | florida; colorado |
| 3 | new jersey |  |  |
| 1 | hawai | utah |  |

I'm trying to group by ID, and merge column `x, y, and z` into one column.

Output should be :

| ID | geo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | new york; california; hawai; utah |
| 2 | vermont; new york; carolina n; oregon; texas; florida; colorado; florida |
| 3 | new jersey |

I tried with the following piece of code :

```
save = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ';'.join(set(x)))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stack the data before join:

```
(df.groupby('ID',group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: '; '.join(x.stack().dropna()) )
   .reset_index(name='geo')
)
```

Output:

```
   ID                                                geo
0   1               new york; california; hawai; utah 
1   2  vermont; new york; carolina n; florida; oreg...
2   3                                        new jersey
```