# Convert csv File format with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am not familar with pandas, now.
I have a csv file, which has the format and some other columns, simplified here:

```
USER; so; ROLE
hugo; a; role_x
hugo; a; role_y
hugo; b; role_x
hugo; b; role_y
otto; role_x
```

and I need the output in this form, where the role category should be listed only once:

```
USER; ROLES
hugo; role_x, role_y
otto; role_x
```

I do this with iteration and dictionary. Is this easier by pandas?

With the referenced solution I get something like:

```
USER; ROLES
hugo; role_x, role_y, role_x, role_y
otto; role_x
```

But the result should show the same role only once.

Comment: strongly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/27298178/12846804

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is great for data aggregation and manipulation, you can group by user very easily:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=';')

# Do your grouping
result_df = df.groupby('USER')['ROLE'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()

# Change the 'ROLE' column to 'ROLES'
result_df.rename(columns={'ROLE': 'ROLES'}, inplace=True)

# Save the result
result_df.to_csv('output_file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Here are some nice examples for how to use the groupby function:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/

Comment: Close the my solution, but not 100%. My failure in the question, sorry.

Comment: @Paul-ET this solution gives your desired output. I just double checked it.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover I edited my question to make it more clear. Thanks for your replay!

Comment: This maybe what you are actually looking for `df.groupby('USER')['ROLE'].apply(set).agg(', '.join).reset_index()`